# Best practices for displaying and managing error messages in React-Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, error-handling, axios, redux-saga

I am building a React app (with [react-redux](https://redux.js.org/), [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/), and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)), and
I need advice on how to arrange my project for displaying user-friendly error messages.

(It is up to me to decide what and how I display to the user)

### In particular, I would like to get answers to the following questions:

1. Should I display a message based on the status code?
2. Should I break down the errors to **client / server / other errors** and what are the benefits of that? (based on [example](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) from Axios)
3. Where should I keep the error messages, in the component itself, in a config file (I would like to see an example of such a file)?
4. How would my redux state tree look?
5. Should I dispatch an action for every error based on the status code?

I would appreciate any suggestions or real-world examples.

### Here are some examples of error responses from our backend:

```
Request URL: https://example.com/api/call/123
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
```

```
Request URL: https://example.com/api/call/123
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 409 Conflict
```

```
Request URL: https://example.com/api/user/me/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 2):

It basically depends on what method you are trying to display the message, For instance, in our own projects, We are using a global snack bar component to display errors if any have occurred during the requests.

1. Most of the time users don't care about the status code, if you want not to be very specific then you can display a simple alert/snack bar for example: "Sorry, Some error occurred".
2. If you are sure that you do need to show specific errors to the user the I definitely recommend a constant file for errors which will store all your error message, You can keep them in constants directory in the store folder so maybe even in /helpers, It depends on your choice.
3. Yep, you can definitely divide your errors based on if the error was on the server or the client-side.
4. I don't think the redux tree will change if you're not managing errors in the tree. If you want to, definitely use a snack bar/alert reducer on the top of the tree
5. You may not want to show the same error for a status code in each of different components, Otherwise, if you want to, You can use it but that would add a lot of unnecessary code into your requests.

For our projects, since we are using i18 for internationalization, We have a snack bar reducer and the action folder, We import the snack bar actions in our sagas and just display a simple error message ( You definitely can customize it for your needs accordingly), That's all,Keep it simple.

```
yield put(Actions.apiRequest);
try {
  const res = yield axios.put('/todo/', updateData);
  if (res.data.status === 'success') {
    yield put(Actions.fetchTodos(todoID));
    yield put(snackbarSuccess('Todo Saved Successfully !'));
  } else {
    throw new Error();
  }
} catch (error) {
  yield put(Actions.apiError);
  yield put(snackbarError(REQUEST_FAIL)); // an imported constant
}
```

Some basic code behind my implementation.

Comment: 3. Yep, you can definitely divide your errors based on if the error was on the server or the client-side.    
- Could you describe more why it is useful, will I show a different message based on if it's a client or server error? Maybe you can give an example. Thanks

Comment: I don't have to believe it'll be useful for any purposes. BTW To divide errors on client/server basis, You should update your API to return a particular error response with the description of the error ( for every error that may happen on the server), for the client-side since you're on react, I would recommend you to have a look at the Error Boundaries if you may possibly have unexpected errors, As of the moment I don't have an example. https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html ( By error here I am not talking about errors caused due to input validations )

Answer (score 1):

1) Assuming you're also doing the BE or can ask someone to adjust the response - It might be best to return a body with your API error response, and avoid just HTTP status codes - if possible. That could then contain an error 'code' that maps to a message on your front-end, as well as field name which can be really helpful for displaying errors in the right place on forms, etc. alternatively, the entire message could come from the BE and the FE simply display it. I work on an enterprise-level codebase that uses both these methods.

2) Regarding error message, i'd always store them in a common file but beyond that up to you really. It sort of depends on how you implement #1. Personally I like error 'codes' stored in an enum file, which correspond to a message because you can then do other logic from that (e.g. don't display the rest of a form if error X is triggered, use a custom message for the error code in one situation or fall back to a default

3) Not sure - I guess you'd do that if you want to log server-side errors but show client. Where I work we differentiate purely for different logging categories I think.

4) Again depends on your implementation - somewhat up to you. Some form packages will handle this for you in redux. Others will just use local state and not redux for this.

5) Would make sense to, yes. Again if you look a custom error code returned in the body of the API call that'll give you more flexibility.

I hope that gives you some ideas, based on my experience rather than any set way of thinking.

have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html as well, and if you haven't already REST APIS / best practice for REST API: https://blog.restcase.com/rest-api-error-codes-101/